# Allow further editing once some other edit approved

Tags: feature-request, edits, approval

I'm not sure if this is already possible so I'll just ask.

Someone made an edit to a question that went into the review queue and, since it looked okay, I approved it. It then moved into the state where it needed at least one other approval to be actioned, `edit(1)`.

However, shortly after that, I noticed some more improvements could be made so I tried to edit it again. It came up with the screen stating:

> You have already reviewed this item, it needs more reviews from other users to be completed.

Now I realise I probably should have checked it more thoroughly before approving (and chosen "improve edit") but this seems like an unnessesary limitation.

Is there a way to, having approved anothers edit, to then go and make more changes (including what you've already approved of course)?

---

Not that it matters (this is more of a generic issue) but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024201/unix-find-command-in-shall-script) is the post that sparked this question. The change I noticed after was the use of "shall script" instead of "shell script".

Comment: The original edit (which I now approved) already corrected all instances of "shall".

Comment: @Cody, appreciate you approving the edit. This may happen for other people/questions so I just wanted to confirm it's still a valid issue (which is probably the case since you didn't close it). Whether it's actually considered a *useful* feature is, of course, still up for discussion :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's a valid feature request. I'm not convinced that it's really worth developer time, and I'm also concerned that there may be potential abuse vectors, but I can understand how it is frustrating to have full edit privileges, yet not be able to use them.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126249) for a workaround.